# Linearity of conditional mean

Tags: probability, expectation

Suppose that the conditional mean of $Y$ given $x$, that is, $E(Y|x)$, is linear in $x$. Now i'm trying to understand why that means the following, given that the continuous random variable $Y$ follows a normal distribution for each $x$:

$$E(Y|x)=\mu_Y+\rho \dfrac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(x-\mu_X)$$

I encountered this formula on the top of this page [Conditional Distribution of Y Given X](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/118). That's a course from Penn. It doesn't define $\rho$, and though it refernces to the previous lessons, notes of the previous lesson don't contain the formula.

Comment: As long as you don't define the symbols you are using, that doesn't mean *anything*.

Comment: Linearity of conditional mean does not mean that. It simply says $E(Y|X)=g(X)$ where $g$ is linear.

Comment: This is true for Bivariate Normal $(X,Y)$ which you should mention in your post.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks, i updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your linearity condition, we have

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}[Y \, | \, x ] = \alpha + \beta x,\label{eq:lin}\tag{1}
\end{equation}

for some constants $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$. Letting $f_X(x)$ denote the probability density function of $X$ we have

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E} \big[ \mathbf{E}[Y \, | x ] \big] & = \int f_X(x) (\alpha + \beta x) d x \\
& = \alpha + \beta \int x\, f_X(x) dx \\
& = \alpha + \beta \mu_x \label{eq:ee}\tag{2},
\end{align*}

where we denoted $\mathbf{E}[X] = \mu_X$ as you do in the question. However, by the law of total expectation

$$
\mathbf{E} \big[ \mathbf{E}[Y \, | x ] \big] = \mathbf{E}[Y] = \mu_Y \label{eq:totalex}\tag{3}
$$
and hence combining $\ref{eq:ee}$ and $\ref{eq:totalex}$ we have
$$
\alpha = \mu_Y - \beta \mu_X,
$$
which is to say
$$\mathbf{E}[Y \, | \, x] = \mu_Y + \beta(x - \mu_X).$$

It remains then to show that $\beta$ can be expressed in terms of the standard deviation, and correlation of $X$ and $Y$. To do this, you will want to use a similar method, and the [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).